# Tmux copy the selection to /dev/clipboard without key-mapping

Tags: cygwin, tmux, clipboard

Many answers related to this topic suggest to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to a command that pipes `tmux show-buffer` to `xclip`. In the specific case of cygwin, the correct way to interract with the Windows clipboard is to use `/dev/clipboard`.

I would like to configure tmux to automatically save a mouse selection into this file. Is it possible without key mapping?

Answer (score 0):

tmux has an additional command :save-buffer *filename*

I haven't seen the examples you referenced piping `tmux show-buffer` to `xclip`. I have used a mapping change to do something similar with `:save-buffer /dev/clipboard`.

Integrate `:save-buffer /dev/clipboard` with your copy-selection mapping. My tmux.conf contains the following line:

```
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-selection \; save-buffer /dev/clipboard \; send-keys -X cancel # Yank selection in copy mode, copy to windows clipboard, cancel copy mode
```

I'll guess you want something similar to that but pertaining to your mouse selection (which I'm unfamiliar with). Like this?

```
    bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-selection \; save-buffer /dev/clipboard \; send-keys -X cancel
```

Reference you may enjoy: OpenBSD tmux man page. Their man pages are generally very complete. 
Buffer utilization: http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#BUFFERS
Search the page also for "send-keys" for info.